# I want to give serial numbers for particular IDs in existing colomns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, row-number

I have **Products** table and 5000 records are there, and I need to update serial numbers for 2000 records.

**old table**

```
Id  Name   Price  Recommended
45  Lotus  450    500
55  Cherry 560    500
56  Berry  789    566
```

**new table**

```
Id  Name   Price  Recommended
45  Lotus  450    1
55  Cherry 560    2
56  Berry  789    3
```

Comment: so you want to do what update sequential numbers in place of Recommended Old numbers

Comment: Yes only for Particular ids

Comment: why upto 2000 only

Comment: not 2000...only Particular products i want to do

Comment: and what are these particular IDs ? are they random?

Comment: ya that products are randomly took

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unfortunately, use a window function directly in the `set` clause. You could, however, use it in a subquery, and then join that query on your table when updating:

```
UPDATE p
SET    p.recommended = rn
FROM   products p
JOIN   (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recommended) AS rn
        FROM   products) r ON p.id = r.id
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65e48/1/0)**

Comment: I mentioned where condition with some Random products(Priority wise) ids in sub query..  but its not getting that Priority

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_number() over ( order by (select null)), *
from OldTable
```

Comment: There is no null values

Comment: @Maybe - row_number() over ( order by (select null)) - is expression to generate sequential numbers for range of lines

Answer (score 0):

you can try with cte

```
   ;WITH cte AS
    (   
        SELECT  
               id,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recommended) AS rn, 
               name,
               price

        FROM   Products
    )
    UPDATE  cte
    SET recommended = rn
    -- if you have any condition put here for example ( where rn <= 2000)
```